# Why is my XCircuit diagram corrupt?

Tags: texstudio, eps, circuits

I am trying to draw some circuit diagrams using XCircuit and imporing the .eps file in TexStudio. How the image is supposed to look:
[image]

and this is how it looks once latex has generated the pdf:

[image]

notice how some of the elements are off, they are all misaligned. When compiling, latex converts the .eps into a .pdf so I have two versions in the same location. The location of the files are all in the same folder. I am using TexStudio

```
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{simple_switch_pulse.eps}
    \caption{Simple switch with inductive load.}
    \end{figure}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: attempting using a simple test project with overleaf results in the .eps displaying correctly. So it has something to do with my install. What can I do to figure out the issues with my install?

Comment: Unfortunately your code can‘t compile when we copy it; we don‘t have your .eps. Please add the missing parts. Thank you

Comment: To me, it seems the issue is caused by the fonts being changed in TeX and the new font having other metrics.

Comment: @Gaussler if this is the case how I rectify it?

Comment: @ChrisD91 Are you sure you want to? Usually, you’ll want the font in the picture picture to reflect the fonts in your document. If the document font causes elements to look misaligned, you should probably edit the .eps file instead. Alternatively, you can probably change the font locally (inside your `figure` environment) to something that looks more like the original font. As a start, you can try running `\sffamily` before the .eps to change from typewriter font to sans-serif. I don’t know enough about .eps rendering in LaTeX to say for sure whether or not this will work, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the question up and provide this answer just in case it helps someone out with writing a technical document using latex and XCircuit. By default the XCircuit font is Helvetica. Installing the Helvetica package in Miktex didn't solve the issue. If you select Times-Roman in XCircuit then that is the Windows standard font of Times New Roman which is fine. Helvetica doesn't seem to be a standard font in Windows (certainly not on my machine anyhow - Windows 10). If viewed in Evince or GIMP then the .eps font seems to work but it's not compatible with the latex to pdf conversion. So just change it as explained.